# NULL values in object properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Tables: `Article`, `Author`, `Comment` (1 article and 1 author can have * comments)

In the database is 1 article, 1 author and 1 comment.

The problem is, that code

```
 myBD my_bd = new myBD();
 var articles = by_bd.Article;
```

works OK, I can see that an `Author` and an `Article` has 1 comment.

But that code

```
    var comm = (from u in my_bd.Comment
                     where ......
                     select u);
```

returns the comment but it has NULL values in property `Article` and `Author`. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support Lazy Loading (yet) and is pessimistic by default. In order to get linked object as collections you have to include them in your query explicitly.

```
var comm = from u in my_bd.Comment.Include("Article").Include("Author")
           where ......
           select u;
```

By doing this you are explicitly telling EF to do the joins when it creates the query. Now you should be able to select those properties.

Comment: Thank for Your post, now it's working :)
btw, do You know some good books/ebooks about Entity Framework ?

Comment: In fact I do happen to know a good E-Book on EF: (http://msmvps.com/blogs/brianmadsen/archive/2009/04/10/free-500-page-pdf-on-the-entity-framework.aspx) It is worth noting however, that you might want to start looking at what is possible with Entity Framework 4 as it will be very different from what you are working with now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using .Include in your initial query, you can use explicit loading using the .Load() method, e.g. myCustomer.OrdersReference.Load()

There are apparently differences in how many sql queries are executed and how much data is transmitted.

Explained well here: http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/is-lazy-loading-in-ef-4-evil-or-the-second-coming/