# Why an associated object is null?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

Let's say I have a Employee table and a Department table, with the DepartmentID as a FK in Employee table. When I retrieve a particular employee, through entity framework, shouldn't the associated department object too should be there as a reference object in the employee object? I see both FkDepartmentID(int) and Department objects, but the Department object is null, at run-time. How would I get the department name? I mean I wanted to take it straight forward using something like;

```
string deptName = employee.Department.DepartmentName
```

But this gives me an error, because the Department object is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer here:
[NULL values in object properties in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251974/null-values-in-object-properties-in-entity-framework)

Apparently, the query should be written as:

```
var emps = from e in Employee.include("Department") select e;
```

Then I could lazy load the Department as:

```
string deptName = employee.Department.DepartmentName
```

Comment: If you are using lazy fetching which is default fetch type, then until and unless you call your Department reference object explicitly from Employee reference while you are still in transaction it will return null only.

Comment: but even with the reference to Departmentname through employee.Department.DepartmentName, I was seeing Department as null.